# Как импортировать множество изображений? Vite/Svelte

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vite, svelte

Для использования статики, а именно изображений, используют `import moduleName from 'module'`:

```
import urlImg from './assets/img.svg'
import urlImg2 from './assets/img2.svg'
import urlImg3 from './assets/img3.svg'
...
```

далее, следует захламление импортами при большем множестве изображений.

Как подключать статику более лаконично, **например** объектом с путями?

```
paths = {
  img: {
    urlImg: './assets/img.svg',
    urlImg2: './assets/img2.svg',
    urlImg3: './assets/img3.svg'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в каталоге /assets/ файл index.js, в него импортируйте изображения и экспортируйте их же.

```
// ./assets/index.js

import urlImg from './assets/img.svg'
import urlImg2 from './assets/img2.svg'
import urlImg3 from './assets/img3.svg'

export { urlImg, urlImg2, urlImg3 }
```

Подключаете модуль в нужном месте и выбираете нужное вам изображение

```
import { * as images } from './assets/index.js'

console.log(images.urlImg3);
```

Comment: Тут следует вопрос - как быть в случае огромной базы изображений? Как сделать лаконичнее?

Comment: @RoNULL Смотря где эта "огромная база" хранится. Если это всё локальные файлы, то я не представляю как, кроме ручного добавления.

Comment: Кстати, почему-то ваш способ выдает ошибку "Cannot find name 'images'
Cannot find name 'images'. Did you mean 'Image'?, но я чуть подредактировал: import { images } from './assets/js/index.js' и export const images = { viteLogo, swiperLogo, svelteLogo } - это, благо, работает

Comment: Делали пирог по вашему рецепту из авокадо, кешью и барбариса. Авокадо не было, взяли яблоки, вместо кешью взяли грецкий орех, а барбарис решили не добавлять. Попробовали, не вкусно. Фигня ваш рецепт... Вот и тут так же, кто же его знает, без примера кода, почему возникает та или иная ошибка. **Cannot find name 'images'** больше похоже что вы пытались получить доступ к переменной images из импорта, хотя в примере она объявлена как алиас для *. Покажите, где появляется ошибка, тогда, скорее всего, и ответ найдется

Comment: Прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Подозреваю, что это "особенности" svelte.

Comment: Ниже ответ уточнил вашу ошибку, отредактируйте свой ответ при возможности

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as images from './assets/index.js'
```

без фигурных скобок импортироать надо в этом случает